# Why does allocated size of permanent generation increase after executing perform GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, permgen

Following are the snapshots I took after executing **perform GC** from jvisualvm.
[image: Heap Stats]
and
[image: Permgen Stats]

First image is Heap stats and 2nd one is perm gen stats. I am not able to understand when I did GC **utilized heap size** decreased(as expected) but the allocated size of permanent generation increased (though the utilized permgen size remained the same).`What could be the possible explanation of such behavior?`

JVM arguments used

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:../xyz.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:../abc.jar
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=../resolver
-Djava.library.path=../framework
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=JBeanServerBuilder
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=../certs
-Dorg.mortbay.log.class=JettyLogger
-Xms128m
-Xmx256m
-Xdebug
-Xnoagent
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=2000
```

Note : I have changed the name(ex xyz.jar) for propriety reasons.

JVm Info:

```
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.7.0_11, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: /home/aniket/jdk1.7.0_11/jre
JVM Flags: <none>
```

Comment: I'd guess that the GC reevaluates the various sizes it has to control as part of the collection run. So it might decide that it is a little tight on the perm gen side of things an increase it.

Comment: Which VM/gc do you use, with what params do you start the VM?

Comment: @JensSchauder: that's probably the best answer one can make for this question without much speculation about HotSpot internals...

Comment: @JensSchauder added JVM params to the Q.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy added JVM info and params used.

Comment: you could try to log at the GC logs, maybe they'll give you an indication on whats going on. Use -verbose:gc -Xloggc:file to turn on GC logging, maybe combined with -XX:+PrintGCDetails

Comment: lol looks strange, tested the same and when my heap decreases, my permgen decreases too.

Comment: Could you maybe provide the "PermGen histogram" in the Sampler, so we can see what actually changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The memory-allocation Heap/Perm/Eden/Young/S1/S2 etc spaces depends on the underlying algorithm used for GC.
- Memory allocation to above spaces are not defined as absolute values parameters. They are defined as ratios to total heap / perm available to JVM.
- Above two points probably point out that when Heap size changes, all memory allocations to all spaces are re-evaluated to maintain the ratio which are defined.

Below link will be really useful:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 1):

since nobody offers an answer, I make my comment an answer, although it is a little vague:

I'd guess that the GC reevaluates the various sizes it has to control as part of the collection run. So it might decide that it is a little tight on the perm gen side of things an increase it.